# CustomReuseStrategy giving - Cannot find primary outlet to load 'ProductComponent'

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-router

I have an Angular 2 app with several tabs for different features/components. 
One of the tabs is "Products" where I can see the list of products and search for products by typing name in a search field. I can then click on the product to view its details and then come back to the main products tab. Now, I do not want to lose the search text and results on the products page. To solve this issue, I looked at the CustomReuseStrategy

My app.routing file looks somewhat like:

```
const appRoutes: Routes =
    [
        {
            path: '',
            component: MainComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    canActivate: [CanActivateGuard],
                    children: [
                        { path: 'orders', component: OrderComponent },
                        {
                            path: 'products',
                            canActivate: [FeatureEnabledGuard],
                            component: ProductsComponent,
                            data: { shouldDetach: true},
                            children: [
                                { path: '', component: FindProductComponent,  data: { shouldDetach: true} },
                                { path: ':id', component: ProductDetailsComponent, data: { shouldDetach: true} },
                            ]
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

My CustomReuseStrategy class looks like:

```
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouteReuseStrategy, DetachedRouteHandle } from '@angular/router';

export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {

    handlers: {[key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle} = {};

    shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        if(route.routeConfig.data) { 
            return route.routeConfig.data.shouldDetach;
        }
        return false;
    }

    store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
        console.log('CustomReuseStrategy:store', route, handle);
        this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path] = handle;
    }

    shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        console.log('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldAttach', route);
        return !!route.routeConfig && !!this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path];
    }

    retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
        console.log('CustomReuseStrategy:retrieve', route);
        if (!route.routeConfig) return null;
        return this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path];
    }

    shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        console.log('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldReuseRoute', future, curr);
        return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
    }

}
```

With this, when I do a search on products page, I get some results. I click on a product and can view the product details. Now, I go back to the Products tab and I see the results and search saved which is perfectly what I want. But, now when I navigate to a different tab say "Order" tab, it works fine. Then I come back to the Products tab. I still see the search text and results as before which is good. But, now when I click on the specific product to its details page, it fails. And I get an error:

Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'FindProductComponent'. Why do I get this error? I am quite lost on what the issue is. Any ideas?

Something seem to just get messed up when using combination of sibling and child routes